# Get Data From Structs With String Key, And Struct to Array

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to get a value from a struct using a string key?
Like this:

```rs
struct Messages {
    greetings: String,
    goodbyes: String
}

impl Structure {
    fn new() -> Structure{
        Messages {
            greetings: String::from("Hello world"),
            goodbyes: String::from("Bye!")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let messages = Messages::new();
    // now how do I print it out with a string key?
    println!("{}",messages["greetings"]); // prints "Hello world"

    // and can I even turn a struct into an array? Function name is made up
    let arr = Struct::to_array(messages);
}
```

Pls help thz

Comment: no, it;s not possible. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: loop through a structure to print it out in a tic tac toe format (I'm still learning rust)
I'm doing a 9x9 tictactoe board so it is gonna be painful to type everything out (I stored data in 0,1 and 2)

Comment: What you are asking is possible but I doubt that a new rust learner would require such a workaround. For your question, you can see [Index trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and you can automate its generation by macros.

Comment: @Siriusmart maybe I am not understanding but would you mind elaborating your tic-tac-toe issue a little more?

Comment: ok thx I will try that

Comment: @Siriusmart, just adding to this, from personal experience I feel [rust-lang discord channel](https://discord.gg/rust-lang) will be more helpful while new to Rust :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no, this is not possible. The names of your fields aren't necessarily available at runtime to perform such a check. However, there are other ways to achieve similar results:

- use a `HashMap<String, String>`
- write a function to do it:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
  pub fn get_field(&self, key: String) -> &str {
    if key == 'field1' {
      self.field1
    } else if ...
  }
}
```

- Write a derive macro to generate the above function automatically (https://crates.io/crates/field_names might be a useful starting point for how you might go about writing a derive macro)

### Or solve it a different way

This pattern is not well supported in Rust, especially compared to more dynamic languages like JavaScript. A problem many new Rust learners face is solving problems "the Rust way".

It's not 100% clear from your comment, but it sounds like your struct is representing a tic-tac-toe board and looks something like this:

```rust
struct Board {
  top_right: String,
  top_middle: String,
  top_left: String,
  // etc...
}
```

While this works, there are much better ways of doing this. For example, you could represent each tile with an `enum` instead of a `String`, and you could also use an `Vec` (similar to arrays/lists from other languages) to store that data:

```rust
enum Tile {
  Empty,
  Cross,
  Circle,
}

struct Board {
  tiles: Vec<Tile>,
}

impl Board {
  pub fn print(&self) {
    for tile in self.tiles {
      println!("{}", match tile {
        Tile::Empty => " ",        
        Tile::Cross => "X"
        Tile::Circle => "O",
      });  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless the size of the board is dynamic, it would probably be easier to represent it as a 2D array: `tiles: [ [ Tile; 3]; 3]`

Comment: 100% agree. In this answer I felt like using a `Vec` made more sense, since it's likely a more familiar type to someone asking this sort of question, and I wanted to keep the potential "new concepts" to a minimum